# React, typescript and prop-types: how to use own type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have a string type literal, something in the form of `type MyType = 'str1' | 'str2' | 'str3'` and I want one of my props to accept only this type, but I have no idea how to tell PropTypes.

I've tried to use `propTypes.oneOf(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'])` but then typescript infer it as a normal string, which I don't want.

Comment: If you use TypeScript >=3.4, try `propTypes.oneOf(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'] as const)`. I don't use `props-types` so not 100% sure it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is type checking with TypeScript, you don't try to do it at the React runtime level (`propTypes`), you do it at the TypeScript level.

Your component should use your string literal type in its props type:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
    propName: MyType;
}
```

Then if its a class component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, /*...your state type here...*/> {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you're using a functional component:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({propName}) => {
    // ...
};
```